# SQL - TOP 1 and MIN doesn't work but MAX works

Tags: sql, max, min

I have a strange bug here.

I'm trying to limit the result from the query below to just ONE row/result:

```
SELECT userEmail
    FROM [LunchUsersAvailable]
    WHERE LunchGroupsID = '301' AND availableDate = '2015-01-01' AND userEmail != 'userEmail@company.com' EXCEPT
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT (COALESCE([user1], [user2])) AS matchedEmail
        FROM
        (
                SELECT [user1], [user2]
                FROM [LunchMatched]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT [user2], [user1]
                FROM [LunchMatched]
        ) AS tmp
        WHERE (user1 = 'userEmail@company.com' OR user2 = 'userEmail@company.com')
    )
```

**OUTPUT:**

test2@company.com

test3@company.com

test4@company.com

---

I tried using **TOP 1**. Didn't work. No results at all.

```
SELECT TOP 1 userEmail
    FROM [LunchUsersAvailable]
    WHERE LunchGroupsID = '301' AND availableDate = '2015-01-01' AND userEmail != 'userEmail@company.com' EXCEPT
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT (COALESCE([user1], [user2])) AS matchedEmail
        FROM
        (
                SELECT [user1], [user2]
                FROM [LunchMatched]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT [user2], [user1]
                FROM [LunchMatched]
        ) AS tmp
        WHERE (user1 = 'userEmail@company.com' OR user2 = 'userEmail@company.com')
    )
```

---

I tested with **MIN()** as well. No results.

```
SELECT MIN (userEmail)  as email
    FROM [LunchUsersAvailable]
    WHERE LunchGroupsID = '301' AND availableDate = '2015-01-01' AND userEmail != 'userEmail@company.com' EXCEPT
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT (COALESCE([user1], [user2])) AS matchedEmail
        FROM
        (
                SELECT [user1], [user2]
                FROM [LunchMatched]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT [user2], [user1]
                FROM [LunchMatched]
        ) AS tmp
        WHERE (user1 = 'userEmail@company.com' OR user2 = 'userEmail@company.com')
    )
```

---

I tested with **MAX()** just in case. **It works!**

```
SELECT MAX (userEmail)  as email
    FROM [LunchUsersAvailable]
    WHERE LunchGroupsID = '301' AND availableDate = '2015-01-01' AND userEmail != 'userEmail@company.com' EXCEPT
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT (COALESCE([user1], [user2])) AS matchedEmail
        FROM
        (
                SELECT [user1], [user2]
                FROM [LunchMatched]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT [user2], [user1]
                FROM [LunchMatched]
        ) AS tmp
        WHERE (user1 = 'userEmail@company.com' OR user2 = 'userEmail@company.com')
    )
```

**OUTPUT:**

test4@company.com

---

In summary, my question is: how do I get the **test2@company.com** as a result?

---

**UPDATE WITH MORE TESTING:**
I've done two different tests. One works, the other one doesn't. I'll show each one in detail. First, the test where everything works fine:

I want to explain each SELECT individually and the result for each part individually:

```
-- this outter SELECT lists all available users who are available
SELECT userEmail FROM [LunchUsersAvailable]
WHERE LunchGroupsID = '301' AND availableDate = '2015-01-01' AND userEmail != 'userEmail@company.com'
```

**OUTPUT:**

test1@company.com

test2@company.com

test3@company.com

test4@company.com

(4 row(s) affected)

---

```
-- this inner SELECT lists all the users who has been paired with userEmail@company.com before
SELECT DISTINCT (COALESCE([user1], [user2])) AS matchedEmail
FROM
(
        SELECT [user1], [user2]
        FROM [LunchMatched]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT [user2], [user1]
        FROM [LunchMatched]
) AS tmp
WHERE (user1 = 'userEmail@company.com' OR user2 = 'userEmail@company.com')
```

**OUTPUT:**

userEmail@company.com

test2@company.com

(2 row(s) affected)

---

Running the full code, **without** the TOP 1, MIN() or MAX():

test1@company.com

test3@company.com

test4@company.com

(3 row(s) affected)

---

This is **all correct** so far. Now I need to get only the **test1@company.com** part so I change the first line of the code from 
    SELECT userEmail FROM [LunchUsersAvailable]
to
    SELECT TOP 1 userEmail FROM [LunchUsersAvailable]

The result is:

test1@company.com

(1 row(s) affected)

---

This is working **absolutely** fine.

But now, if the *userEmail@company.com* has been previously matched with the **test1@company.com instead of the test2@company.com** ([LunchMatched] table) the result is different.

The INNER, OUTTER and the FULL code (without TOP 1, MIN or MAX) works the same way as explained above, which is fine.

**BUT**, if I change the first line of the code from
    SELECT userEmail FROM [LunchUsersAvailable]
to
    SELECT TOP 1 userEmail FROM [LunchUsersAvailable]

The result is **null** and not the correct one:
test2@company.com

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: A side note: Your query is overly complicated. First you select all user1-user2 pairs plus all user2-user1 pairs. Then you remove all pairs where no partner is 'userEmail\@company.com' Then you select the first element of each pair including removing nulls, then you use distinct. And all you *actually* do is: get all user1 plus all user2 of conversations where one partner is 'userEmail\@company.com'. A rather simple NOT EXISTS clause would do here.

Comment: The table _[LunchMatched]_ stores the pairs who has been previously matched (_user1_ and _user2_). But it could save either **userEmail@company.com | userB@company.com** or **userB@company.com | userEmail@company.com**. My code is trying to find all the people who has been matched with userEmail@company.com on the _[LunchMatched]_ table. That's why I need to do a UNION ALL first (to get the pair from both sides). The _SELECT userEmail FROM [LunchUsersAvailable]_ lists all available users, but I don't want to pair userEmail@company.com with the same pair, that's why I use the EXCEPT 'old pair'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! The TOP 1 or MIN is processing **before** the EXCEPT which means that it will first get the TOP 1 from the available users result and only them apply the EXCEPTION.

**Solution**: get the full list of available users, run the exception and only then get TOP 1

```
 SELECT TOP 1 useremail FROM (
    SELECT userEmail
    FROM [LunchUsersAvailable]
    WHERE LunchGroupsID = '301' AND availableDate = '2015-01-01' AND userEmail != 'userEmail@company.com' EXCEPT        -- from a specific cafeteria and date, EXCEPT
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT (COALESCE([user1], [user2])) AS matchedEmail                                                                        -- select all matched users in one column
        FROM
        (
                SELECT [user1], [user2]
                FROM [LunchMatched]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT [user2], [user1]
                FROM [LunchMatched]
        ) AS tmp
        WHERE (user1 = 'userEmail@company.com' OR user2 = 'userEmail@company.com')                                                  -- who has been previously matched with the user who is registering now
    )
) as tmp
```

Comment: Yes that's it. Stupid me not to have spotted this. Only keep in mind that TOP 1 gives you a rather random record as long as you don't specify a sort order with ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

This suggests that `userEmail` takes on multiple values, one of which is the empty string (`''` -- not `NULL`).

The first row returned by `userEmail` has this empty value.  The `min()` would capture it.  The `max()` doesn't.

Put in a check that `userEmail <> ''` or just use `max()`.

If you want the `min()`, you could also use conditional aggregation with a `case`:

```
select min(case when userEmail > '' then userEmail end)
```

EDIT:

I see the problem.  The `top 1`, `min()` and `max()` refer to the first query before the `except`.  I had missed the `except` because it is scrolled off the end of the line.  `except` works like `union`, connecting queries together.  It is not part of the `where` clause.

Comment: Your suggestions seems to work in theory, but is not valid for my question. When running the standard `SELECT userEmail` query the output says _(3 row(s) affected)_ which means there is no empty result.

Comment: I tried running the `SELECT MIN(case when userEmail > '' then userEmail end) as email` suggestion but the result is still _(0 row(s) affected)_

Comment: @criscmaia: If the statements are exactly the same except for MIN(userEmail) instead of userEmail, and you get no row returned, then there really is a bug in your dbms.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of @ThorstenKettner . Any idea how to debug it? If I run **only** the inner _SELECT DISTINCT[...]_ it returns the correct result. The outer _SELECT_ works fine without the EXCEPT part as well. Both together works fine as well. It also works normally with MAX(), BUT it doesn't work with MIN() or TOP 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is no answer. This is just to show how to simplify the original query. Here are three of many possibilities:

```
SELECT userEmail
FROM LunchUsersAvailable
WHERE LunchGroupsID = '301' 
AND availableDate = '2015-01-01' 
AND userEmail != 'userEmail@company.com' 
EXCEPT
(
  SELECT user1
  FROM LunchMatched 
  WHERE user2 = 'userEmail@company.com'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT user2
  FROM LunchMatched 
  WHERE user1 = 'userEmail@company.com'
);
```

Or:

```
SELECT userEmail
FROM LunchUsersAvailable
WHERE LunchGroupsID = '301' 
AND availableDate = '2015-01-01' 
AND userEmail != 'userEmail@company.com' 
AND userEmail NOT IN
(
  SELECT user1
  FROM LunchMatched 
  WHERE user2 = 'userEmail@company.com'
)
AND userEmail NOT IN
(
  SELECT user2
  FROM LunchMatched 
  WHERE user1 = 'userEmail@company.com'
);
```

Or:

```
SELECT userEmail
FROM LunchUsersAvailable
WHERE LunchGroupsID = '301' 
AND availableDate = '2015-01-01' 
AND userEmail != 'userEmail@company.com' 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM LunchMatched 
  WHERE LunchUsersAvailable.userEmail IN (LunchMatched.user1, LunchMatched.user2)
  AND 'userEmail@company.com' IN (LunchMatched.user1, LunchMatched.user2)
);
```

In the second and third query one can easily replace userEmail with MIN(userEmail). In the first one, this would be done via `SELECT MIN(userEmail) FROM (first query here)`.